# Want to call a method with parameters of an listbox from a buttonclick

Tags: vb.net, events, button, listbox

I have this method that looks like this:

```
Public Sub CreateEditbox(sender As Object)
    ListBox1 = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    itemSelected = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    Dim r As Rectangle = ListBox1.GetItemRectangle(itemSelected)
    Dim itemText As String = DirectCast(ListBox1.Items(itemSelected), String)
    EditBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(r.X + 15, r.Y + 15)
    EditBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(r.Width - 15, r.Height)
    editBox.Show()
    ListBox1.Controls.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.Control() {Me.editBox})
    editBox.Text = itemText
    editBox.Focus()
    editBox.SelectAll()
    AddHandler EditBox.KeyPress, AddressOf EditOver
    AddHandler EditBox.LostFocus, AddressOf FocusOver
End Sub
```

Now i want to be able to call this method from a buttonclick, im just not quite sure how i can get the sender data of the listbox, as seen on the first row in the method, from the buttonclick event. Any ideas?

Best regards,

Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the method from a button click then you need to pass ListBox Object.

for ex :

```
CreateEditbox(myListBox)
```

In your case if "sender" is a ListBox then send the listbox itself as an parameter to method.